# related to abstract class reference holding object of its derived class

Tags: java

class A is abstract and class B extends class A
now class A reference can hold object of class B,that is

```
A aObj = new B();
```

and assume class B has some extra methods....
like

```
class A
{
public show();
}
class B extends A
{
public show(){}
public method1(){}
private method2(){}
}
```

now tell me what things variable aObj can access from class B
can it access everything?

Comment: You mean public void show(), and abstract class A :)

Comment: "now tell me". A bit rude. Is this homework or so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aObj can only use show() as the compiler thinks aObj is of type A, and the only known method of A is show().

If you know that you actually have a B you can cast that object to a B:

```
if (aObj instanceof B.class) {
  B bObj = (B) aObj;
  bObj.method1(); //OK
} else {
  log.debug("This is an A, but not a B");
}
aObj.show();
```

Comment: that means...it cant access method1() and method2()?

Comment: @shradda, the `show()` method called via an A reference is implemented in B and as such it (`B::show()`) can call `method1()` and `method2()` although they are not visible through the A reference.

Answer (score 3):

aObj only sees the `public show()` method. If you cast aObj to B, you can then access `public method1()`. `public method2()` is only accessible to the implementation of B.

Answer (score 3):

For reference and completeness, here's a list of the possibilities:

```
A aObj = new B();
aObj.show(); // Works
aObj.method1(); // Error
aObj.method2(); // Error
```

And with casting to B:

```
B bObj = (B)aObj; bObj
bObj.show(); // Works
bObj.method1(); // Works
bObj.method2(); // Works inside bObj, but error otherwise
```